# different uses of ++ in pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand the combination of ++ in pointers. So I code a simple program (in Ubuntu with virtualBox) to see those in action. I initialised an array

```
...
int num[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int  *p,i;

p=num;

printf("num[] = ");
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  printf("%d ", num[i]);
}        
printf("memory location of ptr: %p\n",  (void *)p);
...
```

and then i peform these commands and then I print again the same things as above.

```
*p += 1;
*p++;
(*p)++;
++(*p);
++*p;
```

and the output is:

```
//the array is init with these values
num[] = 1 2 3 4 5 memory location of ptr: 0xbfbed054

----- *p += 1; -----
num[] = 2 2 3 4 5 memory location of ptr: 0xbfbed054

---- *p++; -----
num[] = 2 2 3 4 5 memory location of ptr: 0xbfbed058

---- (*p)++; -----
num[] = 2 3 3 4 5 memory location of ptr: 0xbfbed058

---- ++(*p); -----
num[] = 2 4 3 4 5 memory location of ptr: 0xbfbed058

---- ++*p; -----
num[] = 2 5 3 4 5 memory location of ptr: 0xbfbed058
```

The `*p++` increase the memory location of the pointer so after that he points to the next cell of the array . Is this right? (I suppose the cells of the array are stored continuously in the memory..?
 On the other hand the `(*p)++` increases the value that points.
  I thought that the same thing would happen to the pair `++(*p)` and `++*p`. But as I see the output this didnt happened. It inceased the value of the cell in both times.

Comment: First you might want to check up an [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), then you will see that the two `++` operators have different precedence. You should also be able to figure out what the different operations does with the help of that table

Comment: And as one of the operations changes the actual pointer, still looping from zero to five will read a value from beyond the array, whose value is indeterminate, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: yes i see your point. i Changed it a little bit the code. but i still have the same output.

Comment: my question is actually this. Why after the ++*p the memory location doesn’t change?

Comment: Without contradicting what other comments say, if you want to reverse engineer things, better use a different array `int num[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};` will help you better understand what's going on.

Comment: You may want to try `*++p`.

Comment: Might be easier if you isolate the test expressions... I mean, reset orignal situation before each command. Much easier to see what each does, compared to each others, when the starting state is same. Another note: as your very question demonstrates, apart from a few idiomatic expressions, you should generally avoid any "clever" code which combines changing pointer itself and getting the value it points to into same expression. Compiler should produce same binary even if you write more readable code (unless it is "toy" code or for learning purposes).

Comment: hmm i will!!! what it does?

Comment: it increases the memory location of the pointer, right? @n.m.

Comment: +1 because it's a sensible question and welcome change to see someone do some proactive experimentation and ask for guidance in interpreting the results, rather than just "please debug my code".

Comment: Thank you! I just want to understand what I code and know what it does before I execute it and not trying to understand the code through the result. Thats why I ask so much 'simple' things..

Comment: yes it increases the address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) you will see that the prefix increase (and decrease) operators have the same precedence as the dereference operator `*`, and that both these operators are evaluated *from right to left*. That means that `++*p` is really the same as `++(*p)`.

That is also why `*p++` increases the *pointer*, because the suffix `++` operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator.